# Submitting a form with jQuery/Ajax only works every other time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, yui

I'm trying to submit a form which includes a file upload via Ajax/jQuery, process the form through a PHP script, and return the result in the div that the form originally resided in.

My current form code is:

```
<section id="content-right">
<form name="uploader" id="uploader" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760" />
    <input type="file" name="fileselect" id="fileselect" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</section>
```

And my current Ajax/jQuery script is:

```
<script> 
$(function() {
$('#uploader').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: 'upload-song.php',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#content-right').html(response);
                }
            }); 
    return false; 
    });
});
```

My PHP script is "upload-song.php" (the details don't matter).

I also have YUI.Pjax running to handle normal navigation (a href) links and load those in #content-right (if a user clicks anything, I want it loading in #content-right).

With this set up, navigating through normal links works perfectly, everything loads in #content-right, but the uploader only works every other time.

For example, the uploader will load upload-song.php in #content-right and process everything perfectly, then if I navigate away from the page and try to upload another item, it won't work, it'll just refresh the page (if I put action="upload-song.php" in the form tag it'll load upload-song.php as a full page, not in #content-right). After it refreshes the page I can upload another item and it will work perfectly.

I think it has to do with how I'm attaching my Ajax script to the form submit (because if I refresh the page it works perfectly), but I don't have a lot of experience with these languages so I'm not sure how to fix it.

In addition, if I disable YUI.Pjax it fixes the uploader but obviously breaks my links, so I'm looking for a work around.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the PHP page being called every time or do you know for certain that the problem is in the javascript?

Comment: The PHP page is not being called every time via Ajax/jQuery. It gets called every other time. If I add an action tag to the form field it will submit the form via Ajax and then submit the form via the action tag, but if I leave the action tag out it will simply refresh the page. As I said, I think a workaround would be possible within the javascript but this is due to a conflict that I can't figure out between that javascript and YUI.Pjax (if I disable YUI.Pjax) the upload script works 100% of the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#uploader", function() ...
```

This syntax will let the submit event bubble up to the document. That way, when the `#content_right` section reloads, the document retains the event listening response set up in the DOM ready function.

Comment: Thank you! You are a god. (I'd upvote this but I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Thanks. Just pay your tithe please! :)