# Jquery and ajax for submitting form doesnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

this is my code for for submitting my form:
aj.js
   $(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#reqForm").submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var f = e.target,
    formData = new FormData(f),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", f.action,true);
    xhr.send(formData);
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
        {

        $("#alert").html(xhr.responseText);
        $('#alert').css('visibility','visible').fadeOut(5000);  
        }
    }
});

});
```

at the first time when submit the form, all things is good and all mycode run well. but when i want too submit for the second, third ,.. time the ajax code done and form data save in database, but this part of my code doesnt work

```
 xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
        {

        $("#alert").html(xhr.responseText);
        $('#alert').css('visibility','visible').fadeOut(5000);  
        }
```

my insert file:

```
$result=mysqli_query($dbCnn,"insert into request (name,telNum,email,request,date)           values('$_POST[name]',$_POST[tel],'$_POST[email]','$_POST[request]',NOW())");
if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbCnn)<1)
    $_SESSION['alert']="success!!";
  else
      $_SESSION['alert']="NOT!";
  echo $_SESSION['alert'];

}
```

?>

Comment: have you looked in your console for an error?

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem, but `formData` and `xhr` should be local variables, not global variables.

Answer (score 0):

it is very clear that `xhr.onreadystatechange` is not firing after the first time.

I am not sure if this is the solution. but the way you registered the form submission could have an impact.

So try linking the submit event to the root document so that it will bubble every  time you submit and reload  , like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on("submit","#reqForm",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var f = e.target,
    formData = new FormData(f),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", f.action,true);
    xhr.send(formData);
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
        {

        $("#alert").html(xhr.responseText);
        $('#alert').css('visibility','visible').fadeOut(5000);  
        }
    }
});

});
```

I hope that will work out

---

answer is inspired from : [Submitting a form with jQuery/Ajax only works every other time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741746/submitting-a-form-with-jquery-ajax-only-works-every-other-time?rq=1)

==========
EDIT:

There are some thoughts on SO answers that the order does matter, so you first `open()` the Ajax request then set your event `xhr.onreadystatechange=function()` then use `send()`

If what I read is true then it should work

Try it and let me know

Comment: hi,tnx for your answer, I have copied and pasteed your code, But the it works sameas my code. and the problem exist.